# Why would a new repository automatically install packages?

Tags: package-management, repository

Is there a situation where a newly-added repository would need to install "dependency" packages before being asked to install anything new?

I just came across the following situation:

While my system was up-to-date, I added the *Certbot* repository (http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu), and after running an update, nine packages were reported to be upgradable. I tried to do an upgrade and got the following:

```
$ sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
Resolving dependencies...                
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-certifi{a} python3-idna{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python-chardet python-pkg-resources python-six python3-chardet python3-configobj python3-pkg-resources python3-requests python3-six python3-urllib3 
9 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 906 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,183 kB will be used.
```

I can understand packages being upgraded: the new repository has newer versions of packages already installed on my system, so they're marked for upgrade. But why is it trying to install **new** packages? The packages in question certainly seem relevant to the [software on the repository](https://certbot.eff.org/), but why would they be installed automatically?

If they are a dependency for something on my system, how was it working before? How can I investigate exactly what's going on?

**UPDATE**

I checked the reverse dependencies with `apt-cache`; e.g.,

```
$ sudo apt-cache rdepends python3-certifi
python3-certifi
Reverse Depends:
python3-requests
```

With the *Certbot* repository disabled, I get

```
$ apt-cache depends python3-requests
python3-requests
Depends: python3-urllib3
Depends: <python3:any>
    python3:i386
    python3
Depends: ca-certificates
Depends: python3-chardet
Depends: python3-urllib3
```

and when I enable it, I get

```
$ apt-cache depends python3-requests
python3-requests
Depends: python3-certifi
Depends: python3-chardet
Depends: python3-idna
Depends: python3-urllib3
Depends: <python3:any>
    python3:i386
    python3
Depends: ca-certificates
Depends: python3-urllib3
```

So, I guess, the real question becomes: **are package dependencies a function of available packages/repositories**? I thought dependencies should be fixed: a package either requires another package to work (whether it is available to you or not) or it doesn't (in which case, it's not really a dependency).

**System**:

- Kubuntu 16.04
- Kernel 4.13.0-45-generic #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu 64-bit

Comment: The output shown just indicates that there's a new version of `python3-requests` with different dependencies. Of course dependencies aren't the same for all versions of a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the commands suggested by [N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert) and with some help from the good people at the OFTC #debian IRC channel, I traced it back through the packages and figured out why this happened, which is probably the most likely scenario when seeing unexplained new packages automatically installed:

The newly-added repository contained a newer version of an existing package, which was marked for upgrade. **The new version of the upgraded package had a new dependency (that the older version didn't have), so the new dependency was marked for automatic installation**.

For example, the upgraded version of the existing package `python3-requests` has `python3-certifi` as a new dependency, so the latter was marked for installation.

It was my fault that I originally missed the fact that the reverse dependency of `python3-certifi` (`python3-requests`) was one of the packages being upgraded.

Answer (score 4):

You have already answered your question: PPA have newer versions of already installed packages, so after adding PPA and running `apt-get update` APT sees that newer versions are available and lists some packages as having updates.

You can get details by running `apt-cache policy`:

```
apt-cache policy python-chardet python-pkg-resources python-six \
python3-chardet python3-configobj python3-pkg-resources python3-requests \
python3-six python3-urllib3
```

and check their origin (see *Version table*).

Also you can check from where two new packages will be installed and why they will be installed (check with `apt-cache rdepends`):

```
apt-cache policy python3-certifi python3-idna
apt-cache rdepends python3-certifi python3-idna
```

You can consult [`man apt-cache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html) for details.

Comment: Does `apt-cache rdepends` require the packages to be installed to work properly (the manual doesn't specify)? It's not showing me anything useful regarding dependencies, but I haven't actually installed the packages in question.

Comment: Usually `apt-cache` is pre-installed as it is a part of `apt` package.

Comment: I meant I hadn't installed `python3-certifi` and `python3-idna`, but anyway, it was my mistake: I was looking at `apt-cache policy` instead of  `apt-cache rdepends`.  Will update info in my question.